# php если цифры меньше двух цифр

Tags: php

у меня есть файл там есть данные, добавляю их в базу по критериям, есть 4 критерии

[image: данные]

добавляю их в базу по критериям в CONTACT_TYPE нормирую по цифрам 
например 
если только цифры тогда = 3

если иметься @ = 4 итд

помогите пожалуйста с таким вопрос, если цифра меньше двух цифр то тогда критерия = 2
Например если цифра 1 или 12 в файле то критерия = 2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
if(isset($lstContact[0])) {

for ($i=0;$i<=count($lstContact)-1;$i++)
{
  $contacttype="0";
  if(substr($lstContact[$i],0,1)=='+') $contacttype=2;
  if(strpos($lstContact[$i],'@')){ $contacttype=4;
    if ($CONTACTSmail=='') $CONTACTSmail= $lstContact[$i];
   }
  if((strpos($lstContact[$i],'+')===false) && (strpos($lstContact[$i],'@')===false) && ($i!=0)) $contacttype=3;
  if($i==0) $contacttype=1
}
}
```

Comment: первое что в голову пришло - сравнивать числа с 10 (<10 || <=9 == true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто пишите в программе ровно то, что говорите своими словами:

```
if (preg_match("/^\d{1,2}$/", $lstContact[$i])) {
    $contacttype = 2;
}
```

А именно: если всё содержимое строки от её начала `/^` и до её конца `$/` составляют цифры `\d` в количестве одна или две `{1,2}`, то тип контакта `= 2`.